# Does abstract class methods have a body or not?

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

I had came through a theory that abstract class methods doesn't have a method body, only the method signature. And although a method didn't assigned abstract keyword in a method declaration it automatically convert to an abstract in JVM.
So how come this eat() method has a body and how come it doesn't get to override in Swan class.

```
public abstract class Animal {

    protected int age;

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Animal is eating");
    }

    public abstract String getName();
}

class Swan extends Animal {

    public String getName() {
        return "Swan";
    }
}
```

Comment: "I had came through a theory that abstract class methods doesn't have a body" where did you read that? We would like to know to avoid this source (or maybe you misunderstood it so we could try clarify it). You just posted counterexample which works fine so...

Comment: @Pshemo this method doesn't have a body in abstract class, public abstract String getName();

Comment: There's a difference between an "abstract method" and a "method in an abstract class".  Your example contains both.

Comment: If by "this method" you mean `getName()` then indeed, it doesn't have body in abstract class since it was defined as abstract method and that is fine. But as you shown `eat()` method has body despite being placed in abstract class which counters theory that "abstract class methods doesn't have a body". In short, abstract methods don't have body, and must be declared in abstract class, but that doesn't mean that all methods in abstract class must be abstract.

Comment: @Pshemo so you are saying that only absract methods doesn't have method in abstract class. Normal methods like eat() can have a method body, right?

Comment: @pippilongstocking "only absract methods doesn't have method in abstract" you forgot to add "body" before "in". But let me rephrase your sentence: abstract method not only don't have body, it *can't* have body in class in which it was declared. That is what makes it *abstract*. Such class only give us promise that some of its subclass which will not be abstract will contain body for it, but at abstract class level we don't need or don't know how body for that abstract method should look like. We let that decision about implementation be made at subclass level.

Comment: Methods which are not declared as abstract (in abstract class) will not be considered as abstract so they *must* have body.

Comment: @Pshemo thank you so much that clear explanation. Also I fixed that method body mistake in the question. Thank you again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html):

**Abstract Classes Compared to Interfaces**

Abstract classes are similar to interfaces. You cannot instantiate them, and they may contain a mix of methods declared with or without an implementation.

If you define a method, then it can be referenced just like any other super class method.

Comment: Then how come eat method in abstract class automatically override when swan class is extending the Animal class? Is that becuase its a normal method?

Comment: `eat()` is not being overriden. If you call `eat()` it would in your code, call the super class method. However, you can override eat() as well if you want.

Comment: The reason eat() can be overridden in Swan class, is because that you can override the super class method right?

Comment: Yes, unless a method is declared as `final` in a class, you can always override it in your subclass.

Comment: Lets say for argument sake both Animal class and getName() method is not abstract. And if Swan class extend the Animal class still both eat() and getName() can be overrriden or implemented as super class methods right?

Comment: @AnindyaDutta you cannot override a private method regardless it be final or not

Comment: @Doleron true, Private methods do not have scope outside their class.

Comment: The cited link is a tutorial, not 'the Oracle docs', which would comprise one or more of the JLS, the JVM Specification, or the Javadoc.

Comment: A tutorial is still documentation, even though it's not normative.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem But it isn't '*the* Oracle docs', which is what I actually stated.

Comment: @pippilongstocking if the AnindyaDutta's answer worked for you consider to mark as accepted/upvote: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

> I had came through a theory that abstract class methods doesn't have a method body, only the method signature.

That's not a theory, it is a fact, specified in the [JLS #8.4.3.1 'Abstract methods'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.1), but it applies to abstract *methods*, not to all methods in an abstract *class*.

> And although a method didn't assigned abstract keyword in a method declaration it automatically convert to an abstract in JVM.

No it doesn't. Nothing about it in the [JLS #8.1.1.1 'Abstract classes'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1).

> So how come this eat() method has a body

Because it isn't abstract.

> and how come it doesn't get to override in Swan class.

I don't know what this means.

Answer (score 1):

> I had came through a theory that abstract class methods doesn't have a
>   method body, only the method signature.

As it happens, both Java classes and methods can be abstract.  An abstract method is a method that may only have a signature.

Among other things, an abstract Java class:

- may contain abstract methods, concrete methods, or both
- may not be instantiated directly
- defines a type (just like an interface does)

A concrete Java class:

- may not contain abstract methods (only concrete methods are allowed)
- may be directly instantiated
- can define a type, but interfaces (and sometimes abstract classes) are often better used for this purpose